# Angular providers: Use existing or create one if not provided

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In Angular 2+, how can I provide a new instance of an `Injectable` only if there's no instance existing?

I searched and found none so I tried `useFactory`. This is my code so far:

```js
{
  provide: ColorsService,
  useFactory: (colorService: ColorsService, colors: string[]) => {
    if (colorService) return colorService;
    return new ColorsService(colors);
  },
  deps: [ColorsService, MY_COLORS],
},
```

Besides the fact that I'm injecting the `MY_COLORS` token manually, I get a weird error:

> Error: Circular dep for ColorsService

Comment: Why aren't you just declaring it as `providedIn: 'root'`?

Comment: Because It's not a root service. I need different instances of this service in different components. But I need that when I provide it in a parent component, all child components would use the provided instance

Comment: Then provide the service in that parent component? https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#multiple-service-instances-sandboxing

Comment: @eko the parent component isn't always there. sometimes it's `<parent><child></child></parent>` and sometimes it's `<child></child>`. I want the child component to provide the service if there's not parent component

Comment: Ok then try `@SkipSelf` https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#skipself

Comment: @eko Thanks a lot. I shared my solution. Would you please check to see if that's what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, looks good to me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So with the help of @eko I found this solution:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ColorsService],
})
export class ChildComponent {
  colorService: ColorsService;
  constructor(
    @Self() currentColorService: ColorsService,
    @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentColorService?: ColorsService,
  ) {
    this.colorService = parentColorService ?? currentColorService;
  }
}
```

In this example, the `parentColorService` is the service that might be provided by a parent component. If it's not provided, I'll use the `currentColorSerivce` which is instantiated in this component (it's instantiated anyway which may not be a good thing).

Comment: You should accept this answer as the solution

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this won't work if another component up in hierarchy (lets call it 2nd) will also implement this on the same service. In such case 2nd component will get its parent's service, but 1st component will get 2nd component's service! (not its parent), resulting in two different services being used :(

Answer (score 13):

There is another way to achive that.

```js
{
  provide: ColorsService,
  useFactory: (parentInjector: Injector, colorService?: ColorsService) => {
    if (!colorService) {
        const injector = Injector.create({ providers: [{ provide: ColorsService }], parent: parentInjector });
        colorService = injector.get(ColorsService);
      }

      return colorService;
  },
  deps: [ Injector, [ new Optional(), new SkipSelf(), ColorsService ] ],
}
```

this way, every children will also be able to inject the right service

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, if I dont inject ColorsService anywhere in parent component I got NullInjectorError. The service is not created when no parent provides it

Comment: My bad! I needed to twek my code a little, it does seems to work. Great answer, thanks